# C : struct to json string

Tags: c, json, struct

I want to convert struct to json string, is it possible?
for example:

```
struct data{
   int a;
   int b;
}
struct data myData;
myData.a = 1;
myData.b = 2;

char* structToString(struct data myData){
    ......
}

output:
     myData{
         a : 1,
         b : 2,
     }
```

How can I implement this function(structToString)?

Comment: Well....you have to write the code for it?

Comment: Write the function to do it yourself. Or use the scores of json C libraries publicly available.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's very much possible.

A JSON object is nothing more than a string with a specific format. You will need to allocate memory for your string, and fill it with the various elements that need to be in it. "Filling up" your string is easily done using the [strcat()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm) function.

Your JSON object starts with a '{'. Then variables are listed in the following format:

```
"variable_name":"value"
```

each variable is separated by a comma. The object ends with a '}'.

Using this, you should be able to do it yourself..

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project https://github.com/tamask1s/zax-parser

With the help of the library you can have such functionality if you provide meta information on your struct members which needs to be converted to JSON.

The lib is quite immature because I have implemented the features I needed only, but you may extend it with more features, or you may use it as inspiration. You will need a c++11 compiler in order to compile.

```
struct data
{
    int x = 7;
    string name = "seven";
};

#define some_json_props JSON_PROPERTY(x), JSON_PROPERTY(name)

data some_obj;

char json_string[1000];

zax_convert_to_json(json_string, sizeof(json_string), some_obj, some_json_props);
```

json_string's value will be: {"x":7, "name":"seven"}

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into [cisson](https://gitlab.com/Meithal/cisson). Following example from their README is simple enough to implement what you are looking for:

Let's turn the following C object into JSON

```
struct foo = {
  .foo = "bar",
  .array = {1, 2, 3},
  .question = true
};
```

```
#define CISSON_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "cisson.h"

int main(void) {
    struct tree tree = {0};
    
    START_AND_PUSH_TOKEN(&tree, ROOT, "#custom root");
    /* every token we push will be bound to the current root */
    START_AND_PUSH_TOKEN(&tree, OBJECT, "{");
    PUSH_ROOT(&tree);
    /* "PUSH_ROOT" will change the current root to the previously
     * pushed token so every following
     * token will be bound to the object token */
    START_AND_PUSH_TOKEN(&tree, STRING, "\"foo\"");
    PUSH_ROOT(&tree);
    /* next token will be bound to the key */
    START_AND_PUSH_TOKEN(&tree, STRING, "\"bar\"");
    CLOSE_ROOT(&tree);
    /* now the root is no more the key but the object */
    START_AND_PUSH_TOKEN(&tree, STRING, "\"array\"");
    PUSH_ROOT(&tree);
    START_AND_PUSH_TOKEN(&tree, ARRAY, "[");
    PUSH_ROOT(&tree);
    START_AND_PUSH_TOKEN(&tree, NUMBER, "1");
    START_AND_PUSH_TOKEN(&tree, NUMBER, "2");
    START_AND_PUSH_TOKEN(&tree, NUMBER, "3");
    CLOSE_ROOT(&tree); /* the array */
    CLOSE_ROOT(&tree); /* the object property */
    START_AND_PUSH_TOKEN(&tree, STRING, "\"question\"");
    PUSH_ROOT(&tree);
    START_AND_PUSH_TOKEN(&tree, TRUE, "true");
    puts(to_string(&tree)); /* {"foo":"bar","array":[1,2,4],"question":true} */
}
```